# Android and multi choice dialog

Tags: android

I have a multichoice dialog, but I have a small problem. This is code:

```
    int in;
protected void showSelectMeasurementsDialog() {
      boolean[] checkedMeasurements = new boolean[measurements.length];
      int count = measurements.length;

      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)

              checkedMeasurements[i] = selectedMeasurements.contains(measurements[i]);
    in = 0;
      DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener measurementsDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecselectedMeasurementsChecked){
           if(isChecselectedMeasurementsChecked)
               if(in<3){
                   selectedMeasurements.add(measurements[which]);
                   in++;
               }

          else{
            selectedMeasurements.remove(measurements[which]);
            in--;
          }

          onChangeSelectedMeasurements();
        }
       };

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Select Measurements");
      builder.setMultiChoiceItems(measurements, checkedMeasurements, measurementsDialogListener);

      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
    }
protected void onChangeSelectedMeasurements() {
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  for(CharSequence colour : selectedMeasurements)
    stringBuilder.append(colour + ",");

}
```

everything works great and I have a list with some elements. But I want to add functionality that I can't select more than 3 elements. Now I can select all elements from list. I would like to implement that I can select only 3 elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just have a counter variable and if it equals 3 then onClick says you can't select anymore and if its more then you set that dialog item to unchecked. I haven't tried that but it might work. However, a better way, especially if you are going to be adding more functionality to this, would be to consider using an `Actviity` with a `dialog theme`. All you need to do is add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to that `Activity` in your `manifest` and it will give the appearance of a `dialog` with all the functionality of an `Activity`. Hope this helps

Comment: I know what should looks the way to achive that, but I need solution how can I do that in code.